# Where to find the OS that I installed using Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I ran the following commands on the terminal:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox celery-test
docker-machine env celery-test
eval $(docker-machine env celery-test)
docker run -it --name="simple_flask" ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

This downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu and started the terminal as the `root`.

Then I installed `python3`, `pip3` and `celery`. I tried to install `erlang` but somehow the terminal stopped responding after sometime so I had to close it. Now I don't know how to get back to the terminal.

How do I start the terminal of Ubuntu? Where is the image stored?

Comment: see `docker exec` the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 3):

When you did a `docker run` two things happened:

- A container named "simple_flask" was created.
- The container was started with `bash` as the process in an interactive mode with a TTY.

If you closed the terminal you likely killed the interactive session, which killed the `bash` process, which moved the container into a `stopped` state because `bash` exited.

At this point, you have some options:

- You can run `docker ps` to see if the container is still running. If it is, you may likely still be able to attach to the main process running (`bash`) using `docker attach simple_flask`.
- You can list all containers with `docker ps -a` to see running and stopped containers. If the container is stopped, you might be able to start it again and attach to it using `docker start -a -i smiple_flask`.
- You can commit all the pending file system changes to a new image and start that image. Use `docker diff simple_flask` to see what has changed in the image and `docker commit simple_flask flask_image1` to create a new image `flask_image1` with those changes. Then you can start a new container based on this image with `docker run -it --name="simple_flask2" flask_image1 /bin/bash`.

Hope this helps a little bit with some container fundamentals.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the previous image with the new image? Or do I need always create a new image and delete the old one.

Comment: No, the container file system changes are a new layer on top of the existing image. You cannot swap that out of the original container.

Comment: I asked this because you had renamed the container to `simple_flask2` in the last command.

Comment: Yes, i started that new container _after_ committing the file system change to a new image. In this case, the new container contents would be the same as the first.